# Unable to save user made Array to UserDefaults

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I'm making my first app which has a to-do list. The list items are stored in an array and displayed on the Table View, however when closing the app the items are no longer there. I've tried using User defaults to save the items, but it hasn't worked so far. What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to use a button that saves the data.

```
///button to save the data
 @IBAction func savelist(_ sender: Any) {

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(list, forKey: "SavedArray")
    myTableView.reloadData()
}
//// retrieving the data
 override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let array = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "SavedArray") ?? [String]()
    myTableView.reloadData()

}
```

I've also made it so that when I press the save button, the array will be printed to the console so that I know that the items are being added into the array. The problem is that I can't save those items. Thanks!

Comment: Does list contains custom nsobject subclasses?

Comment: what's the `list`? and are you sure it is type of `[String]`?

Comment: my array is called list and the strings are inputted by the user. And yes, I'm sure is a String type. It does not contain custom nsobject subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue:
my array was called list, however, when retrieving the data after closing the app I was using

`let array = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "SavedArray") ?? [String]()`

So I changed it to:

```
 list = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "SavedArray") ?? [String]()
```

I also added suggestions made by previous answers. I set the defaults as a global variable and I added

```
        defaults.synchronize()
```

to the button action

Comment: You do not neee to call `synchronize`

Comment: @Paulw11 a synchronize call is still necessary to prevent the case where a user terminates the app before the next automatic synchronization happens in which case the data would not actually be saved

Comment: @zfetters that is not true. Synchronise is only required where defaults may be accessed across threads. UserDefaults uses a write-through cache. New values are persisted to disk immediately. Synchronize ensures that in-memory cached values are refreshed with the on-disk values

Comment: @Paulw11 do you have a link for that information? Because the documentation for synchronize states that it writes any modifications to the persistent domains to disk and updates unmodified persistent domains to what is on disk. Also it states that you should use synchronize if you cant wait for automatic synchronization such as when the app is about to exit. https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize

Comment: The only case where it is required if the app is exiting is if you write defaults in `applicationWillTerminate` As then there may not be time for the automatic write. In all other cases the user cannot react fas enough; try and force quit an app by swiping up fats enough to not save the defaults

Answer (score -1):

Your issue does not seem to be retrieving the string array, but adding the elements to the array.

Consider defining your list if you have not already as [String]:

```
    var list = [String]()
```

If you wish to add an element to the array use the following:

```
    list.append(txtField.text!)
```

I hope this solved your issue. Good luck!